# NoClassDefFoundError loading class with URLClassLoader

Tags: java, reflection, urlclassloader

We are trying to support plugins for our product and I am using reflection to load a class from a jar.

I create a URL ClassLoader and add all the dependency jars as URLs.

I use that ClassLaoder to load the primary class of the plugin.

I get an instance of the class and a Method reference (a run() method).

When I invoke the method I get this exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

This class is in log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, which is included in the classpath of the ClassLoader.

I can see the URL in the classloader in debug so I know its properly referenced.

Sometimes I get a different error, saying that it can't initialize one of my classes but that class is nothing special, no statics or anything.

The primary class that's being loaded by reflection is calling a second class that uses Log4j 2.

When the primary class run() method tries to instantiate the 2nd class that's where this problem occurs.

There is nothing static in either class other than the Logger.

In the debugger I can see from the Method ref that the class was indeed loaded with the URL ClassLoader we created.

This code has been working for a decade and the only thing we've changed is the upgrade to Log4j 2 in the plugin.
The class doing the reflective plugin load is just a normal class in the classpath of the application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ussing Drizzle's suggestion I get:

```
Exception in thread "ServerStatus:update_timer:" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorException in thread "ServerStatus:update_timer:" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.lang.StringCaused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.SystemPropertiesPropertySource.forEach(SystemPropertiesPropertySource.java:39)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.SystemPropertiesPropertySource.forEach(SystemPropertiesPropertySource.java:39)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.reload(PropertiesUtil.java:330) at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.reload(PropertiesUtil.java:330)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:322) at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:322)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:310) at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:310)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:69)  at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:69)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<clinit>(PropertiesUtil.java:49)    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<clinit>(PropertiesUtil.java:49)
```

Update: Log4j 2 version 2.10.x and later have bugs. Loading classes reflectively reveals the bugs. Switching back to 2.8.2 and the above exception goes away. However, now I get ClassNotFound for one of my classes, still.

Comment: How do you create the `URLClassLoader`?

Comment: new URLClassLoader( getPluginClassPath( url ), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() );
getPluginClassPath() just creates all the URLs for the dependencies

Comment: As you can see above, there is a problem with Log4j 2. As far as build env, that would not be helpful. It is quite complex, using many technologies. This is not a build problem.

Answer (score 0):

Backing Log4j down to 2.8.2 resolved issue.  Its a bug on Log4j. Thanks for the help. Man that was hard to find.

Answer (score -1):

this might be helpful for resolving `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Good idea will try

Comment: I'm not convinced this will be helpful - the OP will likely encounter NoClassDefFoundError when executing your code.
The OP's problem is that their classpath doesn't contain the dependency, and the @K.Taylor - please update the question with your build environment (Maven, Gradle, plain Eclipse etc....) and the community as a whole will be better equipped to answer your question.

Comment: So why this answer is downvoted, the resolution is provided, considering that the required libraries are included in the application.

Comment: No idea. I up voted it. I'll do it again if it will accept it. Actually, that is what showed the bug in Log4j.